# Logging within pytest tests

Tags: python, logging, pytest, python-logging

I would like to put some logging statements within test function to examine some state variables.

I have the following code snippet:

```
import pytest,os
import logging

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
mylogger = logging.getLogger()

#############################################################################

def setup_module(module):
    ''' Setup for the entire module '''
    mylogger.info('Inside Setup')
    # Do the actual setup stuff here
    pass

def setup_function(func):
    ''' Setup for test functions '''
    if func == test_one:
        mylogger.info(' Hurray !!')

def test_one():
    ''' Test One '''
    mylogger.info('Inside Test 1')
    #assert 0 == 1
    pass

def test_two():
    ''' Test Two '''
    mylogger.info('Inside Test 2')
    pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    mylogger.info(' About to start the tests ')
    pytest.main(args=[os.path.abspath(__file__)])
    mylogger.info(' Done executing the tests ')
```

I get the following output:

```
[bmaryada-mbp:/Users/bmaryada/dev/platform/main/proto/tests/tpch $]python minitest.py
INFO:root: About to start the tests 
======================================================== test session starts =========================================================
platform darwin -- Python 2.6.2 -- pytest-2.0.0
collected 2 items 

minitest.py ..

====================================================== 2 passed in 0.01 seconds ======================================================
INFO:root: Done executing the tests
```

Notice that only the logging messages from the `'__name__ == __main__'` block get transmitted to the console.

Is there a way to force `pytest` to emit logging to console from test methods as well?

Comment: You might take a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11877951/148680), posted by py.test's creator. He suggests a pytest plugin that provides a high degree of versatility.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Works for me, here's the output I get: [snip -> example was incorrect]

Edit: It seems that you have to pass the `-s` option to py.test so it won't capture stdout. Here (py.test not installed), it was enough to use  `python pytest.py -s pyt.py`.

For your code, all you need is to pass `-s` in `args` to `main`:

```
 pytest.main(args=['-s', os.path.abspath(__file__)])
```

See the py.test documentation on [capturing output](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/capture.html).

Comment: Sorry. I pasted the code in haste. Please remove the 'assert 0 == 1' from the 'test_one' function to notice the 'problem'. Only when there is some failure (which I forced by having a false assert), py.test seems to print the logging information.

Comment: No problem, I found out how to fix on the command line, looking for a programmatic way.

Comment: you could also redirect the logging output to some file instead of the default implicit stderr.

Comment: @superselector hpk42 is the py.test guy, do listen. IIUC, in your code 
it'd be `logging.basicConfig(filename="somelog.txt", level=logging.DEBUG)`.

Answer (score 387):

Since version 3.3, `pytest` supports live logging, meaning that all the log records emitted in tests will be printed to the terminal immediately. The feature is documented under [Live Logs](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/how-to/logging.html#live-logs) section. Live logging is disabled by default; to enable it, set `log_cli = 1` in the `pyproject.toml`<sup>1</sup> or `pytest.ini`<sup>2</sup> config. Live logging supports emitting to terminal and file; the relevant options allow records customizing:

#### terminal:

- `log_cli_level`
- `log_cli_format`
- `log_cli_date_format`

#### file:

- `log_file`
- `log_file_level`
- `log_file_format`
- `log_file_date_format`

As pointed out by [Kévin Barré](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7505103/k%c3%a9vin-barr%c3%a9) in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4673373/logging-within-py-test-tests/51633600?noredirect=1#comment91175953_51633600), overriding `ini` options from command line can be done via:

> `-o OVERRIDE_INI, --override-ini=OVERRIDE_INI`
>         override ini option with "option=value" style, e.g.
>         `-o xfail_strict=True -o cache_dir=cache`

So instead of declaring `log_cli` in `pytest.ini`, you can simply call:

```
$ pytest -o log_cli=true ...
```

### Examples

Simple test file used for demonstrating:

```
# test_spam.py

import logging

LOGGER = logging.getLogger(__name__)


def test_eggs():
    LOGGER.info('eggs info')
    LOGGER.warning('eggs warning')
    LOGGER.error('eggs error')
    LOGGER.critical('eggs critical')
    assert True
```

As you can see, no extra configuration needed; `pytest` will setup the logger automatically, based on options specified in `pytest.ini` or passed from command line.

#### Live logging to terminal, `INFO` level, fancy output

Configuration in `pyproject.toml`:

```
[tool.pytest.ini_options]
log_cli = true
log_cli_level = "INFO"
log_cli_format = "%(asctime)s [%(levelname)8s] %(message)s (%(filename)s:%(lineno)s)"
log_cli_date_format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
```

The identical configuration in legacy `pytest.ini`:

```
[pytest]
log_cli = 1
log_cli_level = INFO
log_cli_format = %(asctime)s [%(levelname)8s] %(message)s (%(filename)s:%(lineno)s)
log_cli_date_format=%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S
```

Running the test:

```
$ pytest test_spam.py
=============================== test session starts ================================
platform darwin -- Python 3.6.4, pytest-3.7.0, py-1.5.3, pluggy-0.7.1 -- /Users/hoefling/.virtualenvs/stackoverflow/bin/python3.6
cachedir: .pytest_cache
rootdir: /Users/hoefling/projects/private/stackoverflow/so-4673373, inifile: pytest.ini
collected 1 item

test_spam.py::test_eggs
---------------------------------- live log call -----------------------------------
2018-08-01 14:33:20 [    INFO] eggs info (test_spam.py:7)
2018-08-01 14:33:20 [ WARNING] eggs warning (test_spam.py:8)
2018-08-01 14:33:20 [   ERROR] eggs error (test_spam.py:9)
2018-08-01 14:33:20 [CRITICAL] eggs critical (test_spam.py:10)
PASSED                                                                        [100%]

============================= 1 passed in 0.01 seconds =============================
```

#### Live logging to terminal and file, only message & `CRITICAL` level in terminal, fancy output in `pytest.log` file

Configuration in `pyproject.toml`:

```
[tool.pytest.ini_options]
log_cli = true
log_cli_level = "CRITICAL"
log_cli_format = "%(message)s"

log_file = "pytest.log"
log_file_level = "DEBUG"
log_file_format = "%(asctime)s [%(levelname)8s] %(message)s (%(filename)s:%(lineno)s)"
log_file_date_format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
```

The identical configuration in legacy `pytest.ini`:

```
[pytest]
log_cli = 1
log_cli_level = CRITICAL
log_cli_format = %(message)s

log_file = pytest.log
log_file_level = DEBUG
log_file_format = %(asctime)s [%(levelname)8s] %(message)s (%(filename)s:%(lineno)s)
log_file_date_format=%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S
```

Test run:

```
$ pytest test_spam.py
=============================== test session starts ================================
platform darwin -- Python 3.6.4, pytest-3.7.0, py-1.5.3, pluggy-0.7.1 -- /Users/hoefling/.virtualenvs/stackoverflow/bin/python3.6
cachedir: .pytest_cache
rootdir: /Users/hoefling/projects/private/stackoverflow/so-4673373, inifile: pytest.ini
collected 1 item

test_spam.py::test_eggs
---------------------------------- live log call -----------------------------------
eggs critical
PASSED                                                                        [100%]

============================= 1 passed in 0.01 seconds =============================

$ cat pytest.log
2018-08-01 14:38:09 [    INFO] eggs info (test_spam.py:7)
2018-08-01 14:38:09 [ WARNING] eggs warning (test_spam.py:8)
2018-08-01 14:38:09 [   ERROR] eggs error (test_spam.py:9)
2018-08-01 14:38:09 [CRITICAL] eggs critical (test_spam.py:10)
```

---

<sup>1</sup> `pyproject.toml` supported since version 6.0 and is the best option IMO. See [PEP 518](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0517/) for the specs.

<sup>2</sup> Although you can also configure `pytest` in `setup.cfg` under the `[tool:pytest]` section, don't be tempted to do that when you want to provide custom live logging format. Other tools reading `setup.cfg` might treat stuff like `%(message)s` as string interpolation and fail. The best choice is using `pyproject.toml` anyway, but if you are forced to use the legacy ini-style format, stick to `pytest.ini` to avoid errors.

Comment: About the note that `log_cli` must be in _pytest.ini_, it seems you can use `-o` option to override value from command line.
`pytest -o log_cli=true --log-cli-level=DEBUG` works for me.

Comment: @KévinBarré very nice comment and a very useful hint in general, thanks! Updated the answer.

Comment: This is definitely the correct answer when using logging. Although I like to differentiate logs that are inside the tests, and logs that are inside the _system under test_ which should be considered separately.

Comment: @CMCDragonkai unfortunately, `pytest` is somewhat limited in that matter. However, this should be doable with special logging configuration for tests in your app; turn off propagation in your loggers and add a "test handler" that logs to a specified file. This way, `pytest` only logs records coming from tests, while the custom handler takes care about the SuT logs.

Comment: Hi, thanks for this great answer.
One small question - I run my tests with the pytest.ini file and my log messages go to the file, which is great.
What still doesn't go to the file in the actual result line of each test 
`test.py:test_method [None] PASSED` - how can I make those lines go to the file also?

Comment: @OfekAgmon if you want to store `pytest` output, you can use the `--result-log` argument (although note it is deprecated, [here are the alternatives](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/deprecations.html#result-log-result-log)). You can't store `pytest` output and live logging output in the same file, though.

Comment: Hi @hoefling, is there a way to dynamically change the filename pytest.log to include date and time in the filename, so that successive test runs logs will be kept in separate file as opposed to being overwritten?

Comment: @andrea yes, you can change the options programmatically; I can't post snippets in the comments, so check out the answer I gave to a similar issue ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60571980/2650249)). The option to adjust is `log_file` instead of `htmlpath`; should you have any difficulties with that, write a new question and ping me here again, I will add a working example.

Comment: I'm seeing logs for my app, but I'm not seeing any of the logs from packages I am using, is there possibly a reason package logs don't get printed out? The package logs are at the debug level. The package I'm using is [flask_oidc](https://github.com/puiterwijk/flask-oidc/blob/7f16e27b926fc12953d6b2ae78a9b9cc9b8d1769/flask_oidc/__init__.py#L692) just in case you'd like to see how logs are used in the package.

Comment: Live logging sadly also capture logging made by other packages from dependency. Is there a way to avoid this?

Comment: Also in my case problem was with parallel tests execution (switched on with `-n 8` option). Only after disabling parallel execution I saw logs.

Answer (score 60):

Using `pytest --log-cli-level=DEBUG` works fine with pytest (tested from 6.2.2 to 7.1.1)

Using  `pytest --log-cli-level=DEBUG --capture=tee-sys` will also print `stdtout`.

Comment: I wanted to see the logs in the code under test, and it solves my problem too.
In PyCharm 2023.2 I've added the `--log-cli-level=DEBUG` option to the Modify Run Configuration > Configuration > Additional Arguments . I can use it like that  for a given file.

Answer (score 25):

To turn logger output on use send `--capture=no` flag from command line.
`--capture=no` will show all outputs from logger and print statements. If you would like to capture outputs from logger and not print statements use `--capture=sys`

```
pytest --capture=no tests/system/test_backoffice.py
```

[Here](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/capture.html) is more information about "Capturing of the stdout/stderr output"

By default logger output level is "WARNING"
To change log output level use `--log-cli-level` flag.

```
pytest --capture=no --log-cli-level=DEBUG tests/system/test_backoffice.py
```

Comment: Great answer. --capture=no did the trick for me.
For anyone using Pytest with VSCode Test Explorer you can add this by editing your .vscode/settings.json file.

`"python.testing.pytestArgs": [
        "directoryHere",
        "-vv",
        "--capture=no",
        "--log-cli-level=INFO"
    ]`

Answer (score 5):

If you want to filter logs with the command line, you can pass **--log-cli-level** (pytest --log-cli-level)
and logs will be shown from the level you specified and above

(e.g. **pytest --log-cli-level=INFO** will show INFO and above logs(WARNING, ERROR, CRITICAL))

note that: default --log-cli-level is a WARNING if you don't specify it (https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/logging.html)

But if you dont want to use **--log-cli-level** every time use pytest,
you can set **log-level**
in your pytest config file (pytest.ini/tox.ini/setup.cfg)

e.g.

put **log-level=INFO** in pytest.ini (or other config files i mentioned)

when you run **pytest**, you only see INFO and above logs

Answer (score 1):

If you use `vscode`, use following config, assuming you've installed
**Python official plugin** (`ms-python.python`)   for your python project.

`./.vscode/setting.json` under your proj

```json
{
  ....
  "python.testing.pytestArgs": ["-s", "src"], //here before discover-path src
  "python.testing.unittestEnabled": false,
  "python.testing.nosetestsEnabled": false,
  "python.testing.pytestEnabled": true,
  ...
}
```

P.S. Some plugins work on it, **including but not limited to**:

- **Python Test Explorer for Visual Studio Code** (`littlefoxteam.vscode-python-test-adapter`)
- **Test Explorer for Visual Studio Code**(`hbenl.vscode-test-explorer`)

Answer (score 1):

You can read:
[Documentation for logging in pytest](https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/logging.html)
Here is simple example that you can run and get log from foo function.

```
#./test_main.py
from main import foo
import logging

def test_foo(caplog):
    caplog.set_level(logging.INFO)

    logging.getLogger().info('Log inside a test function!')

    assert foo(1, 2) == 5
    /* your test here*/
```

```
# ./main.py
import logging

def foo(a, b):
    logging.getLogger().info('a: ' + str(a))
    logging.getLogger().info('b: ' + str(b))
    return a + b
```

Now you can run pytest and get log info from function that you need.
If you don't have any errors, logs will be omitted.