# py.test logging control

Tags: python, pytest

We have recently switched to py.test for python testing (which is fantastic btw). However, I'm trying to figure out how to control the log output (i.e. the built-in python logging module). We have pytest-capturelog installed and this works as expected and when we want to see logs we can pass --nologcapture option.

However, how do you control the logging level (e.g. info, debug etc.) and also filter the logging (if you're only interested in a specific module). Is there existing plugins for py.test to achieve this or do we need to roll our own?

Thanks,
Jonny

Comment: pytest-capturelog appears to have been replaced by https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pytest-catchlog/

This is mentioned in a number of comments below, but I initially missed this information and attempted to use pytest-capturelog. I'm leaving this comment hoping it'll be more visible and save the next guy from making my mistake.

Comment: Since version 3.3, `pytest-catchlog` is included in the `pytest` framework, so you don't need anything in addition. See [Logging](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/logging.html) section in the docs.

Answer (score 10):

Installing and using the [pytest-capturelog plugin](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pytest-capturelog/) could satisfy most of your pytest/logging needs.  If something is missing you should be able to implement it relatively easily.

Comment: I just tried this with pytest 3.0.6. it worked fine but barks a lot: /pytest_capturelog.py:171 'pytest_runtest_makereport' hook uses deprecated __multicall__ argument
WC1 None pytest_funcarg__caplog: declaring fixtures using "pytest_funcarg__" prefix is deprecated and scheduled to be removed in pytest 4.0.  Please remove the prefix and use the @pytest.fixture decorator instead.
...

Comment: Looks like there is a fork that fixes this issue: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pytest-catchlog/

Comment: You don't need any plugins for that, because all this plugins are deprecated and `the functionality of this plugin has been merged to the pytest core` as said here https://github.com/eisensheng/pytest-catchlog (Fork of `pytest-capturelog`)

Answer (score 10):

As Holger said you can use [pytest-capturelog](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pytest-capturelog):

```
def test_foo(caplog):
    caplog.setLevel(logging.INFO)
    pass
```

If you don't want to use pytest-capturelog you can use a stdout [StreamHandler](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.handlers.html#streamhandler) in your logging config so pytest will capture the log output. Here is an example [basicConfig](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html#logging.basicConfig)

```
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG, stream=sys.stdout)
```

Comment: pytest-capturelog seems unmaintained and throws warnings. Looks like there is a fork that fixes this issue: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pytest-catchlog/

Comment: @DaniloBargen *pytest* has integrated logging features as replacement of `pytest-capturelog` from version 3.3, as mentionned here: https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/logging.html#release-notes

Comment: Hi, thanks for the hint. One remark: actually the method is called ```caplog.set_level(logging.INFO)``` (snake case). See: https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/logging.html#caplog-fixture

Answer (score 8):

A bit of a late contribution, but I can recommend [pytest-logging](https://github.com/saltstack/pytest-logging) for a simple drop-in logging capture solution. After `pip install pytest-logging` you can control the verbosity of the your logs (displayed on screen) with

```
$ py.test -s -v tests/your_test.py
$ py.test -s -vv tests/your_test.py
$ py.test -s -vvvv tests/your_test.py
```

etc... NB - the `-s` flag is important, without it `py.test` will filter out all the `sys.stderr` information.

Answer (score 7):

Pytest now has native support for logging control via the `caplog` fixture; no need for plugins.

You can specify the logging level for a particular logger or by default for the root logger:

```
import pytest

def test_bar(caplog):
    caplog.set_level(logging.CRITICAL, logger='root.baz')
```

Pytest also captures log output in `caplog.records` so you can assert logged levels and messages. For further information see the official documentation [here](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/logging.html#caplog-fixture) and [here](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/reference.html#_pytest.logging.LogCaptureFixture).

Answer (score 1):

A bit of an even later contribution: you can try [pytest-logger](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pytest-logger). Novelty of this plugin is logging to filesystem: pytest provides nodeid for each test item, which can be used to organize test session logs directory (with help of pytest tmpdir facility and it's testcase begin/end hooks).

You can configure multiple handlers (with levels) for terminal and filesystem separately and provide own cmdline options for filtering loggers/levels to make it work for your specific test environment - e.g. by default you can log all to filesystem and small fraction to terminal, which can be changed on per-session basis with `--log` option if needed. Plugin does nothing by default, if user defines no hooks.