# How do I print to console in pytest?

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest

`pytest` will not print to the console when I use `print`. The [documentation](http://pytest.org/latest/capture.html) seems to say that it should work by default.

I am using `pytest my_tests.py` to run this test:

```
import myapplication as tum

class TestBlogger:
    @classmethod
    def setup_class(self):
        self.user = "alice"
        self.b = tum.Blogger(self.user)
        print "This should be printed, but it won't be!"

    def test_inherit(self):
        assert issubclass(tum.Blogger, tum.Site)
        links = self.b.get_links(posts)
        print len(links)   # This won't print either.
```

Nothing gets printed to my standard output console (just the normal progress and how many many tests passed/failed).

And the script that I'm testing contains print:

```
class Blogger(Site):
    get_links(self, posts):
        print len(posts)   # It won't get printed in the test.
```

In `unittest` module, everything gets printed by default, which is exactly what I need. However, I wish to use `pytest` for other reasons.

**Does anyone know how to make the print statements get shown?**

Comment: Maybe stdout is being overwritten. What happens if you use `sys.stdout.write("Test")`? How about `sys.__stdout__.write("Test")`? The latter should always write to the system-defined stdout, which should be the console. If the two commands do different things, then stdout is being changed; if they do the same thing, then the problem is something else.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to see normal print output created during pytest run?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14405063/how-to-see-normal-print-output-created-during-pytest-run)

Answer (score 491, accepted):

By default, `py.test` captures the result of standard out so that it can control how it prints it out. If it didn't do this, it would spew out a lot of text without the context of what test printed that text.

However, if a test fails, it will include a section in the resulting report that shows what was printed to standard out in that particular test.

For example,

```
def test_good():
    for i in range(1000):
        print(i)

def test_bad():
    print('this should fail!')
    assert False
```

Results in the following output:

```
>>> py.test tmp.py
============================= test session starts ==============================
platform darwin -- Python 2.7.6 -- py-1.4.20 -- pytest-2.5.2
plugins: cache, cov, pep8, xdist
collected 2 items

tmp.py .F

=================================== FAILURES ===================================
___________________________________ test_bad ___________________________________

    def test_bad():
        print('this should fail!')
>       assert False
E       assert False

tmp.py:7: AssertionError
------------------------------- Captured stdout --------------------------------
this should fail!
====================== 1 failed, 1 passed in 0.04 seconds ======================
```

Note the `Captured stdout` section.

If you would like to see `print` statements as they are executed, you can pass the `-s` flag to `py.test`. However, note that this can sometimes be difficult to parse.

```
>>> py.test tmp.py -s
============================= test session starts ==============================
platform darwin -- Python 2.7.6 -- py-1.4.20 -- pytest-2.5.2
plugins: cache, cov, pep8, xdist
collected 2 items

tmp.py 0
1
2
3
... and so on ...
997
998
999
.this should fail!
F

=================================== FAILURES ===================================
___________________________________ test_bad ___________________________________

    def test_bad():
        print('this should fail!')
>       assert False
E       assert False

tmp.py:7: AssertionError
====================== 1 failed, 1 passed in 0.02 seconds ======================
```

Comment: hmm...still doesnt log my print statements

Comment: Doesn't work to me

Comment: Adding `-v` or `--verbose` flag helped me. Not sure how it works for others without it

Answer (score 453):

Use the `-s` option:

```
pytest -s
```

### Detailed answer

From [the docs](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/capture.html):

> During test execution any output sent to **stdout** and **stderr** is captured. If a test or a setup method fails its according captured output will usually be shown along with the failure traceback.

`pytest` has the option `--capture=method` in which `method` is per-test capturing method, and could be one of the following: `fd`, `sys` or `no`. `pytest` also has the option `-s` which is a shortcut for `--capture=no`, and this is the option that will allow you to see your print statements in the console.

```
pytest --capture=no     # show print statements in console
pytest -s               # equivalent to previous command
```

#### Setting capturing methods or disabling capturing

There are two ways in which `pytest` can perform capturing:

1. **file descriptor (FD) level capturing** (default): All writes going to the operating system file descriptors 1 and 2 will be captured.
2. **sys level capturing**: Only writes to Python files sys.stdout and sys.stderr will be captured. No capturing of writes to filedescriptors is performed.

```
pytest -s            # disable all capturing
pytest --capture=sys # replace sys.stdout/stderr with in-mem files
pytest --capture=fd  # also point filedescriptors 1 and 2 to temp file
```

Comment: You wouldn't happen to know how to also display logging statements? Like logger.warning for example? Just got it: `--log-cli-level=WARNING` will display all WARNING logs

Answer (score 115):

Using `-s` option will print output of all functions, which may be too much.

If you need particular output, the doc page you mentioned offers few suggestions:

1. Insert `assert False, "dumb assert to make PyTest print my stuff"` at the end of your function, and you will see your output due to failed test.
2. You have special object passed to you by PyTest, and you can write the output into a file to inspect it later, like

   ```py
   def test_good1(capsys):
       for i in range(5):
           print i
       out, err = capsys.readouterr()
       open("err.txt", "w").write(err)
       open("out.txt", "w").write(out)
   ```

   You can open the `out` and `err` files in a separate tab and let editor automatically refresh it for you, or do a simple `py.test; cat out.txt` shell command to run your test.

That is rather hackish way to do stuff, but may be it is the stuff you need: after all, TDD means you mess with stuff and leave it clean and silent when it's ready :-).

Comment: i tried version 1. with pytest 3.8.1
unfortunately it only prints the test function block, but not the output from  print statements :(
any more tricks for this?

Comment: @U.V. - Instead of using the `print()` function, you should put the variable or message you mean to print  __after__ the comma in the assert statement. E.g. `assert False, what_are_you` will 'print out' the value of `what_are_you` in the pytest report.

Answer (score 59):

This is the cleanest way I know to print a single statement to `sys.stdout` (without artificially making your test fail or enabling the `-s` option) - you get to see the specific output you want and nothing more:

1. Add the in-built parameter `capsys` to your test function. (This means that you add `capsys` to the list of parameters, e.g.

```
def test_function(existing_parameters, capsys):
```

2. In your code, simply insert:

```
with capsys.disabled():
   print("this output will not be captured and go straight to sys.stdout")
```

See https://buildmedia.readthedocs.org/media/pdf/pytest/latest/pytest.pdf (2.11 How to capture stdout/stderr output).

Comment: This should be the preferred answer! It seems to work flawlessly without side-effects.

Comment: just in this way I can see my print logs. I did not see the print log by -s option nor by creating a file.

Comment: edit queue is full, can't edit: it is really just `def test_something(capsys): ... ` See https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/fixture.html.

Comment: This does not work with session-scoped fixtures, https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/issues/2704.

Answer (score 20):

I needed to print important warning about skipped tests exactly when `PyTest` muted literally **everything**.

I didn't want to fail a test to send a signal, so I did a hack as follow:

```
def test_2_YellAboutBrokenAndMutedTests():
    import atexit
    def report():
        print C_patch.tidy_text("""
In silent mode PyTest breaks low level stream structure I work with, so
I cannot test if my functionality work fine. I skipped corresponding tests.
Run `py.test -s` to make sure everything is tested.""")
    if sys.stdout != sys.__stdout__:
        atexit.register(report)
```

The `atexit` module allows me to print stuff *after* `PyTest` released the output streams. The output looks as follow:

```
============================= test session starts ==============================
platform linux2 -- Python 2.7.3, pytest-2.9.2, py-1.4.31, pluggy-0.3.1
rootdir: /media/Storage/henaro/smyth/Alchemist2-git/sources/C_patch, inifile: 
collected 15 items 

test_C_patch.py .....ssss....s.

===================== 10 passed, 5 skipped in 0.15 seconds =====================
In silent mode PyTest breaks low level stream structure I work with, so
I cannot test if my functionality work fine. I skipped corresponding tests.
Run `py.test -s` to make sure everything is tested.
~/.../sources/C_patch$
```

Message is printed even when `PyTest` is in silent mode, and is *not* printed if you run stuff with `py.test -s`, so everything is tested nicely already.

Comment: Perfect for outputting custom test metrics.

Answer (score 12):

According to the [pytest docs](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/capture.html), `pytest --capture=sys` should work. If you want to capture standard out inside a test, refer to the capsys fixture.

Comment: It's work for me when need print variable in terminal...

Comment: To pass the `--capture` option in every run of `pytest`, add the line `addopts = --capture=tee-sys` in the section `[pytest]` within the file `pytest.ini` ([documentation](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/reference/customize.html#pytest-ini)).

Comment: It shows `pytest: error: unrecognized arguments: --capture=sys` for pytest 7.0.1

Answer (score 4):

I originally came in here to find how to make `PyTest` print in VSCode's console while running/debugging the unit test from there. This can be done with the following `launch.json` configuration. Given `.venv` the virtual environment folder.

```
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "PyTest",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "stopOnEntry": false,
            "pythonPath": "${config:python.pythonPath}",
            "module": "pytest",
            "args": [
                "-sv"
            ],
            "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
            "env": {},
            "envFile": "${workspaceRoot}/.venv",
            "debugOptions": [
                "WaitOnAbnormalExit",
                "WaitOnNormalExit",
                "RedirectOutput"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can also set this via the Pycharm GUI: go to `Run > Edit Configurations`. There, select the test you want to enable print statements for and add `-s` to the `Additional Arguments` field.

I do it like this, because while I primarily use the Pycharm debugger to debug my pytest functions (i.e. via the GUI), my specific use case also requires me to know what's going on elsewhere in my code and print statements can come in handy for that.

Answer (score 4):

without artificially making your test fail or enabling the `-s` option

```
import warnings

text = "asdf" 

warnings.warn(UserWarning("{}".format(text)))
```

Comment: font:

https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/how-to/capture-warnings.html

Comment: Very nice, does the job. I wanted a warning (indeed) to be printed out once, at the start of the run, in a certain circumstance. The obvious place to do this is conftest.py, in method `pytest_configure`. But at that point, for example, pytest hasn't yet configured its loggers (and they wouldn't be much help anyway).

Answer (score 2):

**I generally use this command:-**

```
pytest -v -rs --html=report.html --self-contained-html test_Suite.py -s
```

the above command also generates a **report.html** file where all the print statements are getting captured and saved. And the `-s` at the last will show the print statements into the terminal too.

Answer (score 1):

If you are working with *pytest.ini*, consider using:

```
[pytest]
...
addopts = --capture=no
...
```

This works well if you are running your tests from an IDE extension which is based on you *pytest.ini*

Answer (score 0):

There are already a lot of good answers, but I want to share why I wasn't able to get logs when I ran `pytest`.

One important note is that each test case *must* start with the `test_` prefix when you write the functions. Without that, there will be no print statements when using `pytest`.

As for the command, I use the following one to get very comprehensive logs:

```
python -m pytest -v -rs <particular_file.py> -s -o log_cli-level=DEBUG
```

By making sure you have the right function names and using my command, you should be able to see console logs for sure.