# Can't get "print" output in colsole with selenium + python

Tags: python, selenium, automated-tests

The problem is, I can't see my print in console, although I should!

```
def test_123(app):
 wd = app.wd
 app.open_page("page_adress")
 time.sleep(3)
 element = wd.find_element_by_xpath("locator").text
 print(element)
```

String from my app file:

```
wd = webdriver.Chrome()
```

My test runs successful.
And one more thing! If after my print command I'm putting some string which leads my test to the crash, I can see print with all other crash information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there a space in the actual print call in your code or is that a typo?  I know in python 3.X with Selenium I've only ever used print as follows:

`print(element)`

Notice there is no space between the print command and the parenthesis.

**Updating**

Ok so now that I've got my head on right (sorry for the idiot first response), let's take a look at the problem.  First things first, when using Selenium and python, I always create a driver object to pass my handle around like so:

`driver = webdriver.Chrome()`

Secondly, if you happen to know the ID of the element, you can use `driver.find_element_by_id('locator')`.  It's a bit more explicit in my opinion if you care to use it.  The big thing though is the first point where you create a driver object.  Try giving that a shot and let me know if it's still not working. :-)

Comment: Oh, unfortunately, with space and without it I have the same result (

Comment: Updated the answer above.  See if that works for you.

Comment: Ok so with those changes it still isn't working for you?  Also, try using by_id instead of xpath:
`element = wd.find_element_by_id("locator").text`

Comment: I have a filling, that my print is going somewhere but not in the console. Because it appears there only with a crash information, when a made my test to crash

Comment: Assuming you set up everything correctly and are running the selenium script through command line you should be seeing your output in the same command line.  Have you tried debugging the script to see specifically what line of code you are getting the error on?  Also, can you post the error you are getting in your command line?

Comment: I've tried many variants of a different locators. I'm pretty sure it has nothing to do with locator. 
UPD: I've got no errors in command line. Test passed successful.

Comment: The element "locator" for sure has text in it correct?  Only thing I can think of now would be that there is no actual text in that particular element and that's why you aren't seeing the print.

Comment: Ok, this is a real locator: element = wd.find_element_by_xpath("//nav/span[.='Практика']").text
And that's what I see if a test will crash after my print http://prntscr.com/c7dqjt

Comment: I think the problem is in pytest framework. For some reason he's not putting my prints in console

Comment: Looking at the line of code you just posted you don't actually have anything in the square brackets [].  Usually you would see something like `[@id='SomeID']`.  Have you tried that yet?  Here is an example of an xpath I'm using that works successfully:
`driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='task_list']/h3").click()`
Notice how I set whatever I'm searching for in xpath (in this case the @id) to be the value you want to find.

Comment: I've found the solution!
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24617397/how-to-print-to-console-in-py-test

Comment: Awesome!!  Glad you found the answer you were looking for.  Best of luck with your application!!

Comment: Thank you for having responded!

Answer (score 1):

> The problem is, I can't see my print in console, although I should!

If you use [behave](https://behave.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) as the [launcher for the Selenium tests](https://testingbot.com/support/getting-started/behave.html), you can solve this by passing `--no-capture` as an argument in your behave command:

```
behave -i  my_feature.feature --no-capture
```

Without this argument, outputs from `print()` are captured and discarded.

Comment: What `behave` command are you talking about? This doesn't seem relevant to the question asked.

Comment: behave is a comand used with the Cucumber tool, this command is used to run .features scenarios in python + selenium environments. But adding the --no-option in the command line should work the same way.