# Does pytest only print information when it fails?

Tags: pytest

I am running some tests with pytests. These tests have `print` statements. 
However when all the tests pass, no info is ever printed. 
It is only when a test fails that along with the info about the failure, all prints that were executed get printed.

Is there a way to print info while the test run even when it passes?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I see normal print output created during pytest run?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14405063/how-can-i-see-normal-print-output-created-during-pytest-run)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`-s` option](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/capture.html#setting-capturing-methods-or-disabling-capturing)

Another way how you can see all print statements is to have a look into degenrated outputs, e.g. if you're using [html](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest-html) reports or [html1](https://github.com/christiansandberg/pytest-reporter-html1) reports, print statements are always captured there even when tests pass.

Comment: Thanks. I tried it, and yes it prints the prints of the test. But unfortunately it also prints the prints of the system I am testing.

Answer (score 0):

You can add as command line argument `--verbose` or shortly `-v` to see whole log. It will include all steps: passed, failed, skipped and etc.

Comment: I am using this. It shows passed skipped instead of a dot. But it does not print the statments

Comment: Oh, sorry. You just should use logger instead of `print` statement

Answer (score 0):

Can get the stdout to appear rather than being captured like this:

```
def test_printing(capsys):
    run_the_test()
    print("something capsys will collect and not display")
    with capsys.disabled():
        print(f"my message to the console")
```

Answer (score 0):

What you can also do is use logger as @Andrai seggusted:

```
import logging

LOGGER = logging.getLogger(__name__)

def test_printing():
    x = 5
    LOOGER.warning("x should be above 2")
    LOOGER.info(f"x is now {x}")
```

Just dont forget you need to run with logging option:
**pytest script.py -o log_cli=true**