# How to make pycharm dump stdout and stderr to console on running pytest?

Tags: python, pycharm, pytest

Usint pytest on Pycharm, I have some long tests for which I want to be able to manually monitor progress of.
Things like neural network training - I want to see loss and progress bar.

Running the same code from a regular function like `main()` gives console output fine.

Running through a pytest test doesn't put anything to console until the test is over.

---

How to make pytest still output to console in Pycharm?

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14405063/how-can-i-see-normal-print-output-created-during-pytest-run/59156707#59156707) and tried `-s` and `--capture=tee-sys` which do basically nothing.

---

Feb 03 2021
Just asked [on pycharm's forum](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360010378159-How-to-run-pytest-via-pycharm-and-have-all-output-in-the-run-window-during-the-test-run-).

Comment: I was initially wrong and now my answer is fixed. It is is Additional Arguments and not Parameters

Answer (score 3):

add `-s` to your `Additional Arguments` in the Run/Debug Configuration.

This will disable the default *pytest stdout/stderr* capturing.

Comment: More detail: I am trying to run a pytorch-lightning test, and some of the tests are long. I have to wait to the end of the run to see the result. `-s` doesn't work. Easily reproducible by downloading their open source https://github.com/PyTorchLightning/pytorch-lightning and running a test.

Comment: `-s` doesn't work for me. I still have to wait for the test to end if I want to see the output in the run window.

Comment: This works for me in pycharm 2022