# Saving pytest logs in a file

Tags: python, logging, pytest

I've seen this question: [py.test logging messages and test results/assertions into a single file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24892396/py-test-logging-messages-and-test-results-assertions-into-a-single-file)
I've also read documentation here: https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/logging.html

Neither comes close to a satisfactory solution.

1. I don't need assertion results together with logs, but it's OK if they are both in the logs.
2. I need all the logs produced during the test, but I don't need them for the tests themselves.  I need them for analyzing the test results after the tests failed / succeeded.
3. I need logs for both succeeding and for failing tests.
4. I need stdout to only contain the summary (eg. `test-name PASSED`). It's OK if the summary also contains the stack trace for failing tests, but it's not essential.
5. Essentially, I need the test to produce 3 different outputs:

   1. HTML / JUnit XML artifact for CI.
   2. CLI minimal output for CI log.
   3. Extended log for testers / automation team to analyze.

I tried `pytest-logs` plugin.  As far as I can tell, it can override some default `pytest` behavior by displaying all logging while the test runs.  This is slightly better than default behavior, but it's still very far from what I need.  From the documentation I understand that `pytest-catchlog` will conflict with `pytest`, and I don't even want to explore that option.

## Question

Is this achievable by configuring `pytest` or should I write a plugin, or, perhaps, even a plugin won't do it, and I will have to patch `pytest`?

Comment: Were you able to figure out a solution for this? I started writing my own logger that is used in my pytest modules but I'm not thrilled with the solution.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `--junit-xml=xml-path` switch to generate junit logs. If you want the report in html format, you can use pytest-html plugin. Similarly, you can use pytest-excel plugin to generate report in excel format.

You can use tee to pipe logs to two different processes. example: `pytest --junit-xml=report.xml | tee log_for_testers.log` It will generate logs in stdout for CI log, report.xml for CI artifact and log_for_testers.log for team analysis.