# How should I log in my pytest plugin?

Tags: python, testing, logging, pytest

I'm building a pytest plugin and I currently log by adding something similar to the following two lines at the top of the plugin file:

```
logging.basicConfig()
log = logging.getLogger(PLUGIN_NAME)
```

However, this does not seem to take into account pytest configuration (through either command line options or ini file) such as the log file path, logger format, etc.

I can manually copy those into my `basicConfig` call, but I assume there's a better facility used across pytest and third party plugins for logging, is there not?

I found quite a bit of logging references in pytest's documentation and code, but all of it was discussing capturing *test logs*. I'm interesting in logging the *pytest plugin* itself.

Comment: This is a great question!  Have you looked at the code for some of the more popular plugins?

Comment: Thanks! I searched the pytest-django and pytest-xdist a bit, but couldn't find anything concrete. To be honest I did not spend a lot of time searching, I kind-of assume I'm missing a resource here.

Comment: I did notice `py.log` (`py` is a package by pytest's team) but this just seem to be a different logging scheme, I could not see how this "plugs into" the pytest logging configuration. It does also seem to be a little deprecated/abandoned.

Comment: I have contributed to several medium sized open source projects, and I doubt you are missing a resource.  This is almost certainly going to be a monkey see, monkey do thing.  Which is what excited me about the question.  I would think someone is going to need to go look and see what is generally being done, and then document it for the rest of us...  But maybe I am wrong and someone will happen by with a nugget of knowledge.  Good Luck, and be sure to let us know what you come up with.

Comment: Thanks. I frequently find myself answer my own questions (this probably says something bad about me). Will definitely do so if no one else will beat me to it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. As you've already found out, `py` is deprecated and will be removed from `pytest` dependencies as soon as all usages of `py` are refactored; don't use `py.log` as well as any other modules from `py` if possible.
2. `pytest` does not have any configuration or common functionality for logging outside of tests. `LoggingPlugin` in `_pytest.logging` is for printing logs "live" (as soon as they are emitted in tests; see [my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4673373/logging-within-py-test-tests/51633600#51633600) for examples). The rest of `_pytest.logging` stuff is for capturing log records in tests.

So, just configure logging in plugins same way as in any other program: create a logger named as your plugin, attach the handlers and you're good to go. An example plugin:

```
import logging
import pytest


class SpamPlugin:

    name = 'spam-plugin'

    def __init__(self, config):
        # turn debug prints on only if "-vv" or more passed
        level = logging.DEBUG if config.option.verbose > 1 else logging.INFO
        logging.basicConfig(level=level)
        self.logger = logging.getLogger(self.name)

    def pytest_sessionstart(self, session):
        self.logger.debug('session started')

    def pytest_sessionfinish(self, session, exitstatus):
        self.logger.debug('session finished')


@pytest.mark.trylast
def pytest_configure(config):
    config.pluginmanager.register(SpamPlugin(config), SpamPlugin.name)
```

Test output:

```
$ pytest -vv
DEBUG:spam-plugin:session started
=================================== test session starts ====================================
platform darwin -- Python 3.6.4, pytest-3.7.1, py-1.5.3, pluggy-0.7.1 -- /Users/hoefling/.virtualenvs/stackoverflow/bin/python3.6
cachedir: .pytest_cache
rootdir: /Users/hoefling/projects/private/stackoverflow/so-51737378, inifile: pytest.ini
collected 2 items

test_spam.py::test_foo PASSED                                                         [ 50%]
test_spam.py::test_bar PASSED                                                         [100%]
DEBUG:spam-plugin:session finished


================================= 2 passed in 0.01 seconds =================================
```

You can of course reuse the format defined for live logs if you want to, although it requires slightly more work because you have to configure the root logger yourself:

```
import logging
import pytest
from _pytest.config import create_terminal_writer
from _pytest.logging import ColoredLevelFormatter, get_actual_log_level, get_option_ini


class SpamPlugin:

    name = 'spam-plugin'

    def __init__(self, config):
        level = get_actual_log_level(config, 'log_cli_level')
        fmt = get_option_ini(config, 'log_cli_format')
        datefmt = get_option_ini(config, 'log_cli_date_format')
        formatter = ColoredLevelFormatter(create_terminal_writer(config), fmt, datefmt=datefmt)
        handler = logging.StreamHandler()
        handler.setLevel(level)
        handler.setFormatter(formatter)
        logging.getLogger().setLevel(level)
        logging.getLogger().addHandler(handler)
        self.logger = logging.getLogger(self.name)

    def pytest_sessionstart(self, session):
        self.logger.debug('session started')

    def pytest_sessionfinish(self, session, exitstatus):
        print()
        self.logger.debug('session finished')


@pytest.mark.trylast
def pytest_configure(config):
    config.pluginmanager.register(SpamPlugin(config), SpamPlugin.name)
```

Test output. Although not visible here, the log level will be colored the same way as in live logs because of `ColoredLevelFormatter`:

```
$ pytest --log-cli-level=DEBUG --log-cli-format='%(asctime)s [%(levelname)8s] %(message)s (%(filename)s:%(lineno)s)' --log-cli-date-format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
2018-08-08 13:26:56 [   DEBUG] session started (plugin.py:25)
================================== test session starts ====================================
platform darwin -- Python 3.6.4, pytest-3.7.1, py-1.5.3, pluggy-0.7.1
rootdir: /Users/hoefling/projects/private/stackoverflow/so-51737378, inifile: pytest.ini
collected 2 items

test_spam.py ..                                                                      [100%]
2018-08-08 13:26:56 [   DEBUG] session finished (plugin.py:29)


================================ 2 passed in 0.01 seconds =================================
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer! What does the `--verbose` flag do, for example?

Comment: It just prints you more information. Check out two outputs of same test run in the answer - the verbose one prints you a list of tests, each one having status `PASSED` or `FAILED`, while the regular output contains test modules with dots, one for each test. It doesn't show you the actual names of tests.

Comment: The example with verbosity was just to demonstrate how you can bind the log level to command line argument; I didn't want to introduce a new argument just for that.

Comment: Ah I didn't notice the `config.verbose` code references before. Thanks again!

Comment: Glad I could help! Great question again, btw. ;)

Comment: Not sure what version of pytest it changed, but `get_actual_log_level` is now `get_log_level_for_setting`