# How to have one logger in every test case?

Tags: python, pytest

I'd like to add additional logging to pytest framework test cases. Currently my idea is like this:
Logger clas with the following configuration (let's say default)

```
import logging
class Logger:
    logger = logging.getLogger()
    handler = logging.StreamHandler()
    formatter = logging.Formatter(
        '%(asctime)s %(name)-12s %(levelname)-8s %(message)s')
    handler.setFormatter(formatter)
    logger.addHandler(handler)
    logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
```

In the conftest I am creating a fixture which is actually an instance of the Logger:

```
#conftest.py
@pytest.fixture
def trace():
    trace = Logger()
    return trace
```

Then I am passing this trace fixture to every test where logging is needed.

```
trace.logger.info("Processing data")
    value = input_data.data["value1"]
```

It does work but I am not sure if there is something better to have one common logger for every test case. Currently it is also needed to pass this fixture to any test I want  to add more traces.

Comment: This is what I needed.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4673373/logging-within-py-test-tests

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to check what's logged by your various tests, `pytest` comes with the battery included fixture named `caplog`. You don't need to build your custom handler as I did when testing with `unittest`.

https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/logging.html

Answer (score 1):

You are misunderstanding how `logging.getLogger()` works. Loggers are some kind of singletons...

`logging.getLogger()` will return the logger object if it has already been instanciated, or creates and return a new one else. If you want to get different loggers, you will need to give them names.

Ex:

```
logger = logging.getLogger("logger1")
```

> You should take a look there, the doc is really complete: https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging-cookbook.html