# Setting dynamic folder and report name in pytest

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest, pytest-html

I have a problem with setting report name and folder with it dynamically in Python's pytest.
For example: I've run all pytest's tests @ 2020-03-06 21:50 so I'd like to have my report stored in folder `20200306` with name `report_2150.html`. I want it to be automated and triggered right after the tests are finished.

I'm working in VS Code and I'm aiming to share my work with colleagues with no automation experience so I'm aiming to use it as "click test to start".

My project structure:

```
webtools/
|── .vscode/
|──── settings.json
|── drivers/
|── pages/
|── reports/
|── tests/
|──── __init__.py
|──── config.json
|──── conftest.py
|──── test_1.py
|──── test_2.py
|── setup.py
```

Code samples:

`settings.json`

```json
{
    "python.linting.pylintEnabled": false,
    "python.linting.flake8Enabled": true,
    "python.linting.enabled": true,
    "python.pythonPath": "C:\\Users\\user\\envs\\webtools\\Scripts\\python.exe",
    "python.testing.pytestArgs": [
        "tests",
        "--self-contained-html",
        "--html=./reports/tmp_report.html" 
    ],
    "python.testing.unittestEnabled": false,
    "python.testing.nosetestsEnabled": false,
    "python.testing.pytestEnabled": true,
    "python.testing.unittestArgs": [
        "-v",
        "-s",
        "./tests",
        "-p",
        "test_*.py"
    ]
}
```

`config.json`

```json
{
    "browser": "chrome",
    "wait_time": 10
}
```

`conftest.py`

```
import json
import pytest
from datetime import datetime
import time
import shutil
import os


from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome

CONFIG_PATH = 'tests/config.json'
DEFAULT_WAIT_TIME = 10
SUPPORTED_BROWSERS = ['chrome', 'explorer']


@pytest.fixture(scope='session')
def config():
    # Read the JSON config file and returns it as a parsed dict
    with open(CONFIG_PATH) as config_file:
        data = json.load(config_file)
    return data


@pytest.fixture(scope='session')
def config_browser(config):
    # Validate and return the browser choice from the config data
    if 'browser' not in config:
        raise Exception('The config file does not contain "browser"')
    elif config['browser'] not in SUPPORTED_BROWSERS:
        raise Exception(f'"{config["browser"]}" is not a supported browser')
    return config['browser']


@pytest.fixture(scope='session')
def config_wait_time(config):
    # Validate and return the wait time from the config data
    return config['wait_time'] if 'wait_time' in config else DEFAULT_WAIT_TIME


@pytest.fixture
def browser(config_browser, config_wait_time):
    # Initialize WebDriver
    if config_browser == 'chrome':
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(r"./drivers/chromedriver.exe")
    elif config_browser == 'explorer':
        driver = webdriver.Ie(r"./drivers/IEDriverServer.exe")
    else:
        raise Exception(f'"{config_browser}" is not a supported browser')

    # Wait implicitly for elements to be ready before attempting interactions
    driver.implicitly_wait(config_wait_time)

    # Maximize window for test
    driver.maximize_window()

    # Return the driver object at the end of setup
    yield driver

    # For cleanup, quit the driver
    driver.quit()


@pytest.fixture(scope='session')
def cleanup_report():
    timestamp = datetime.now().strftime('%Y%m%d_%H%M%S')
    os.chdir("./reports")
    os.mkdir(timestamp)

    yield

    shutil.move("./tmp_report.html", "./%s/test_report.html" % timestamp)
```

In current situation the report is created as `tmp_report.html` in the reports folder, but I don't know how I can force running `cleanup_report()` after all tests are completed and `tmp_report.html` is present and complete in folder. For checking if complete I assume I'd have to verify if all html tags have their closing (or at least `<html>` one).

Can somebody help me with that? If you need some further code portions I'll provide them as soon as possible.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can customize the plugin options in a custom impl of the [`pytest_configure`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/reference.html#_pytest.hookspec.pytest_configure) hook. Put this example code in a `conftest.py` file in your project root dir:

```
from datetime import datetime
from pathlib import Path
import pytest


@pytest.hookimpl(tryfirst=True)
def pytest_configure(config):
    # set custom options only if none are provided from command line
    if not config.option.htmlpath:
        now = datetime.now()
        # create report target dir
        reports_dir = Path('reports', now.strftime('%Y%m%d'))
        reports_dir.mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
        # custom report file
        report = reports_dir / f"report_{now.strftime('%H%M')}.html"
        # adjust plugin options
        config.option.htmlpath = report
        config.option.self_contained_html = True
```

If you want to completely ignore what's passed from command line, remove the `if not config.option.htmlpath:` condition.

If you want to stick with your current impl, notice that on fixtures teardown, `pytest-html` hasn't written the report yet. Move the code from `cleanup_report` to a custom impl of the [`pytest_sessionfinish`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/reference.html#_pytest.hookspec.pytest_sessionfinish) hook to ensure `pytest-html` has already written the default report file:

```
@pytest.hookimpl(trylast=True)
def pytest_sessionfinish(session, exitstatus):
    shutil.move(...)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I've stayed with first suggestion and removed if condition. This works flawlessly.

Comment: @MrTeatime glad I could help!