# Generate Log Python

Tags: python, logging, pytest

I am new to coding and I did not understand why I cannot generate logs after my test case is done.

Here is the code for generating log

```
class LogGen:
    @staticmethod
    def loggen():
        logging.basicConfig(filename=".\\Logs\\automation.log",
                            format='%(asctime)s: %(levelname)s: %(message)s', datefmt='%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p')
        logger = logging.getLogger()
        logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
        return logger
```

And here is the code where I call this method:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from pageObjects.storetest import store_test
from utilities.readProperties import ReadConfig
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
from utilities.customeLogger import LogGen


class Test_001_learning:
    baseURL = ReadConfig.getApplicationURL()
    email = ReadConfig.getUseremail()
    password = ReadConfig.getPassword()
    logger = LogGen.loggen()
    PURCHASEPRICE = "100"
    DOWNPAYMENT = "10"
    HOMEINSURANCE = "10"
    PROPERTYTAXES = "10"
    HOADUES = "10"

    def test_store(self, setup):
        self.logger.info("********* Test_001_Learning ********")
        self.logger.info("********* LOggin test  ********")
        self.driver = setup
        self.driver.get(self.baseURL)
        self.driver.get(self.baseURL)
        self.lp = store_test(self.driver)
        self.lp.setemail(self.email)
        self.lp.setpassword(self.password)
        self.lp.button1()
        title = self.driver.title
        if title == "Dashboard / nopCommerce administration":
            assert True
            self.logger.info("********* Test Pass ********")
        else:
            self.driver.save_screenshot(".\\Screenshots\\" + "test_calculator2.png")
            assert False

        self.lp.button2()
        self.driver.close()
```

But after the test case is done no logs are generated.

Thank you in advanced!

Comment: Is the log file empty or is it not generated?

Comment: is not generated

Comment: How are you calling the tests? I mean the command for running the tests.

Comment: pytest -v -s testCases/test1learning.py

Comment: In the video from youtube is working and is the same code but he  got the 3.6 python version and I got 3.9

Comment: On this page it is described how to create a logger that you can use in multiple classes https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging-cookbook.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, `pytest` overwrites any custom logging configuration with its own one in order to capture any logs emitted in the test run; this is useful to test whether your application emits the logs correctly. You can disable this functionality by turning off the `logging` plugin:

```
$ pytest -p no:logging ...
```

Now no logs will be captured and your own logging configuration is applied.

#### Alternative: live logs

However, `pytest` also has a neat feature of [live logging](https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/logging.html#live-logs); when enabled, it will capture the logs *and* write them to terminal or file or both. You can thus replace `LogGen` with the configuration done in `pytest.ini` or `pyproject.toml`. Example with `pyproject.toml`:

```
[tool.pytest.ini_options]
log_file = "Logs/automation.log"
log_file_level = "INFO"
log_file_format = "%(asctime)s: %(levelname)s: %(message)s"
log_file_date_format = "%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p"
```

In the tests, just use the root logger; no need to configure anything in code:

```
class Test_001_learning:

    def test_store(self):
        self.logger = logging.getLogger()
        self.logger.info("********* Test_001_Learning ********")
        ...
```

Shameless self-promotion: check out [my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51633600/2650249) for more configuration examples.

Comment: If I use pytest -p no:logging all my test cases are starting running

Comment: The ellipsis in the command indicates the spot where you place additional arguments, e.g. `pytest -p no:logging -v -s testCases/test1learning.py`

Comment: Oki doki, thank you! And sorry but I am still learning

Comment: Now I got this error messages: http://joxi.ru/J2bgz3luV7qGwA?d=1

Comment: Probably windows; try wrapping in quotes: `-p "no:logging"`

Comment: Wait, what exactly are you doing? You should invoke the command from the terminal; it looks like you have pasted it in the code instead.

Comment: In the terminal I do the command http://joxi.ru/vAWz8yZTOPRZ92?d=1

Comment: Check what the error tells you - you have pasted the command in the Python code at `customeLogger.py`. Your code is thus not runnable until you fix the code.

Comment: Thank you very much! that was

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227357/discussion-between-iollo-and-hoefling).