# Python logging does not log when used inside a Pytest fixture

Tags: python-3.x, logging, automated-tests, pytest, teardown

I have a Pytest + Selenium project and I would like to use the logging module.

However, when I set up logging in `conftest.py` like this

```
@pytest.fixture(params=["chrome"], scope="class")
def init_driver(request):
    start = datetime.now()
    logging.basicConfig(filename='.\\test.log', level=logging.INFO)
    if request.param == "chrome":
        options = ChromeOptions()
        options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
        web_driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install(), options=options)
    if request.param == "firefox":
        web_driver = webdriver.Firefox(GeckoDriverManager().install())
    request.cls.driver = web_driver
    yield
    end = datetime.now()
    logging.info(f"{end}: --- DURATION: {end - start}")
    web_driver.close()
```

looks like `test.log` is not created at all and there are no error messages or other indications something went wrong.

How can I make this work?

Comment: you are yielding before the actual logging, are you sure the code reaches the `logging.info` part? And do you get a file when you put a `logging.info` directly after the `logging.basisConfig` line?

Comment: I tried it and I don't get the file even when logging directly after the logging.basicConfig.

Comment: I do get a `test.log` file when running `logging.basisConfig` and `logging.info` behind each other directly in a terminal.  So that raises the question if you are actually running that part of the code? Try putting a print statement in the code and see if it is running.

Comment: But are you running them in pytest? When I add a print statement directly before logging.info() it is printed to console.

Comment: I didn't, but maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4673373/logging-within-pytest-tests) post can help you?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Two facts first:

1. `logging.basicConfig()` only has an effect if no logging configuration was done before invoking it (the target logger has no handlers registered).
2. `pytest` registers custom handlers to the root logger to be able to capture log records emitted in your code, so you can test whether your program logging behaviour is correct.

This means that calling `logging.basicConfig(filename='.\\test.log', level=logging.INFO)` in a fixture will do nothing, since the test run has already started and the root logger has handlers attached by `pytest`. You thus have two options:

1. Disable the builtin `logging` plugin completely. This will stop log records capturing - if you have tests where you are analyzing emitted logs (e.g. using the [`caplog`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/reference/logging.html#caplog-fixture) fixture), those will stop working. Invocation:

   ```
   $ pytest -p no:logging ...
   ```

   You can persist the flag in `pyproject.toml` so it is applied automatically:

   ```
   [tool.pytest.ini_options]
   addopts = "-p no:logging"
   ```

   Or in `pytest.ini`:

   ```
   [pytest]
   addopts = -p no:logging
   ```
2. Configure and use [live logging](https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/logging.html#live-logs). The configuration in `pyproject.toml`, equivalent to your `logging.basicConfig()` call:

   ```
   [tool.pytest.ini_options]
   log_file = "test.log"
   log_file_level = "INFO"
   ```

   In `pytest.ini`:

   ```
   [pytest]
   log_file = test.log
   log_file_level = INFO
   ```

   Of course, the `logging.basicConfig()` line can be removed from the `init_driver` fixture in this case.

Comment: I guess a third option would be [`getLogger`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.getLogger) instead of `basicConfig`, giving you access to the root logger regardless. Not sure if it works though.